# Настройка фильтров SquidGuard

Tags: squid

Установил Squid настроил его прозрачность для локальной сети. Разрешил вход пользователям без аунтентификации. Далее установил SquidGuard, т.к. он предназначен для создания фильтров(блокировка порно, скачивания(mp3, avi, flv и т.д), баннеров, рекламы). Действия прозведеные такие в конфиге сквида #nano /etc/squid/squid.conf прописываю путь до squidGuard'a, а именно добавил в конец конфига это

```
redirect_program /usr/bin/squidGuard -c /etc/squid/squidGuard.conf  redirect_children 5  redirector_bypass on
```

Далее лезу в конфиг squidGuard #nano /etc/squid/squidGuard.conf и довожу до такого вида

```
dbhome /var/lib/squidguard/dblogdir /var/log/squidsrc admin {ip 192.168.5.73 }dest adult {       domainlist  adult/expressions}acl { admin {          pass !adult all            }  }
```

ip 192.168.5.73(это клиентская машина, а шлюз 192.168.5.175) По этому пути /var/lib/squidguard/db лежит файл expressions, который содержит сайты и регулярные выражения: expressions содержит:

```
\.mp3$\.avi$rambler.ruya.ru
```

И все равно все грузится без проблем почему не блокируется не могу понять. По дефолтному конфигу сделал. и все равно не пашет. Кто нибудь сталкивался с данной проблемой. В гугле нашел тонну статей но они все сделаны также по ману дефолтного конфига.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А HTTP-трафик точно заворачивается на Squid, проверили, в логах запрос отражается?

Проверьте по пунктам:

1. файлы squidGuard баз сконвертированы в формат Berkley DB:

   /usr/bin/squidGuard -c /etc/squid/squidGuard.conf -C all
2. к файлам настроены правильные permissions:

   chown -R proxy:proxy /var/lib/squidguard/db/*
3. и собственно, сама фильтрация:

   echo http://mail.ru - - GET | /usr/bin/squidGuard -c /etc/squid/squidGuard.conf

И внимательно смотрим лог squidGuard.log.

Comment: tail -f /var/log/squid/cache.log я проверял так.Тажке шлюзом я выставил сервер. Так что он ходит это точно

Comment: И так долго мучался со squidguard но решил вернуться обратно к squid'у. Я так и не смог решить данную проблему. Как советовал weervolf у меня проходит авторизация клиента, но почему то фильтры не цепляются, хотя в сквиде я прописал путь до сквидгард. Без понятия почему так получилось. Но прописал правила в сквиде и все работает.